# Flutter - material design 2 semi transparent appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, transparency, appbar

I want to get effect like this - when scrolled up, appbar is transparent with listview visible below it:
[image]

And scrolled down, only white color - first item below appbar:

[image]

My window layout:

```
return Container(
      color: AppTheme.nearlyWhite,
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        bottom: false,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: AppTheme.nearlyWhite,
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerUserController(
                screenIndex: _drawerIndex,
                drawerWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                animationController: (AnimationController animationController) => _sliderAnimationController = animationController,
                onDrawerCall: (DrawerIndex drawerIndexdata) => _onDrawerCall(drawerIndexdata, _forceRefresh),
                onDrawerTap:(DrawerIndex drawerIndexdata) => _onDrawerTap(drawerIndexdata),

                screenView: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + 8, 8, 8),
                      child: _createAppBar(),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child:
                        Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: _screenView,
                        )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              new FabDialer(_fabMiniMenuItemList, Colors.blue, new Icon(Icons.add))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`_screenView` is simple `Listview().builder()` and it shows `InkWell` widget for each item. My appbar is custom, defined like this:

```
_createAppBar() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      _menuSelected,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22,
                        color: AppTheme.darkText,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      globals.cityName,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: AppTheme.darkerText,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.circular(AppBar().preferredSize.height),
                  child: Icon(Icons.refresh, color: AppTheme.dark_grey,),
                  onTap: () => setState(() => _forceRefresh = true),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

That's how it looks now with first list item visible:

[image]

So, almost there, but when scrolled down, appbar won't be transparent:
[image]

I tried to mess around with setting my appbar backround to color with transparency, without success. Also I need to get my widgets actually overlapped (`ListView` needs to overlap my appbar) and it generates error messages from Flutter.

Any ideas how to do that properly?

Comment: Use opacity for more clear output

Answer (score 3):

set `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` in `Scaffold` widget. Then use `Opacity` widget like this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: Opacity( //Wrap your `AppBar`
          opacity: 0.8,
          child: AppBar(
            title: Text("Demo"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 30,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("Tile: $index"),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's again standard appbar, well I need to check how will it work with my custom navigation drawer.  - edited sorry just realized you mean I can wrap my custom appbar this way. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Stack(
        children:[
          Container(
          color:Colors.white,
          padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child:ListView.builder(
          itemCount:25+1,
            //length + 1 is beacause to show 1st item at the beginning
          shrinkWrap:true,
          itemBuilder:(con,ind){
            return ind==0 ?
              Container(height:70)
              :ListTile(
            title:Text('Item $ind',
                      style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,))
            );
          }
          )
          ),
          Container(
          height:70,
          color:Colors.transparent,
          child:Card(
            color:Colors.white.withAlpha(80),
            child: Row(
            children:[
              Expanded(
                flex:1,
                child: IconButton(
                icon:Icon(Icons.list,color:Colors.black,size:25),
                onPressed:(){
                  //todo
                }
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex:3,
                child: Text('Title',
                           style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,)),
              ),

              Expanded(
                flex:1,
                child: IconButton(
                icon:Icon(Icons.search,color:Colors.black,size:25),
                onPressed:(){
                  //todo
                }
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex:1,
                child: IconButton(
                icon:Icon(Icons.more_vert,color:Colors.black,size:25),
                onPressed:(){
                  //todo
                }
                ),
              )
            ]
            ),
          )
          )
        ]
        )
    );
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you able to scroll list to make first list item not overlapped?

Comment: If you want to see the list items behind the appbar, continue with my answer. If you don't want to see the items behind the app bar then replace Stack with Column

Comment: Sorry, it crashes with error message `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 170 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty':`

Comment: The error is in your code at _positions ! Check there !